# Grails + Gpars.memoize().. how to do memoization?

Tags: grails, groovy, gpars

I can't seem to figure out how to do memoization in Grails. According to the GPars docs it should be as simple as 
`def c = { x -> x*2 }.memoize() or ... .gmemoize()`

But all i seem to get is compilation errors and stacktraces thrown. Has anyone successfully used gpars with grails?

Comment: Can you provide some more informatio, e.g. stack trace and where you are using the memoize() function?

Comment: it was just a test i did, so im not actually using it for anything yet. but what i basically got was that the method doesn't exist. so it doesn't seem like the memoize or gmemoize function actually is injected upon the closure object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grails up until 1.4.0m1 bundled an old version of gpars (0.9) that didn't include memoization. Since Grails preferes the bundled libs to the user-specified ones, you never get a chance to see the memoization methods.
To my best knowledge the Grails master branch has already fixed that and gives users the freedom to choose a GPars version they like.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently successfully using GPars data flow concurrency in a Grails 1.3.7 application. GPars is defined as a basic jar dependency in BuildConfig.groovy, we are not using the GPars Grails plugin.

Comment: I have the same configuration, and im already using `GParsPool.withPool{}` functionality. but `Gpars.memoize()` doesn't seem to exist as a method.